# How to open files directly on Photoshop from a text box Mac Application

Tags: macos, file, photoshop

Hello dear programming community. Hope everyone is staying safe.

I have thousands of image files in hundreds of directories and finding them can take time.

I want to be able to input 5 or 6 file names at a time into a text box and the application would find the images and open them up on photoshop.

Can anyone point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: Are all the images somewhere under your HOME directory? Are you sure you don't have two images with the same name but in different directories?

Comment: Sorry should have been more clear. I have thousands of images in hundreds of different sub directories all in 1 main directory. I wanted to design an app that would open images according to file names from a text box.

Comment: Not sure I understand this. You have thousands of images and you are able to think of the complete names of 6 of them and type those correctly and in full into a text box? Are they all PSD files, or are there PNGs and JPEGs too? What's the fascination with a text box- why not the Terminal?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with Automator and a little `bash` script. Start Automator, and create a new application. Then click `Utilities` (annotated yellow) and then drag `Run Shell Script` (annotated magenta) to the right side (annotated cyan) and drop.

[image]

Now paste the following code into the right side:

```
# You can edit these parameters to suit your local situaton
LOCATION="/Users/mark/Photos"
PHOTOSHOP="Adobe Photoshop CC 2019"

# Pop up a dialog asking for filenames
list=$(osascript -e 'Tell application "System Events" to display dialog "Enter filenames to Photoshop - separate with commas:" default answer ""' -e 'text returned of result' 2>/dev/null)

# Make array of filenames from list, splitting on commas
IFS=',' read -ra fnames <<< "$list"

# Generate full paths of each filename, in another array
fullpaths=()
for f in "${fnames[@]}"; do
     # Try to find file, ignoring case, in specified location
    full=$(find "$LOCATION" -iname "$f" -print 2> /dev/null)
    # Add to list to pass to Photoshop if found
    [ ! -z "$full" ] && fullpaths+=("$full")
done

# Start Photoshop with the specified files
open -a "$PHOTOSHOP" "${fullpaths[@]}"
```

Now save the application on your Desktop, I called mine `FindAndShop`. You can then double-click it to run it. That is all you need to answer your question. The following is just prettification!

Here it is in action:

[image]

---

If you want to, you can change the icon, so I made a new, square icon in Photoshop and copied the image, then I right-clicked my shiny new app, and chose `Get Info`. Now click the cyan area, then on the menu bar at the top of the screen, click `Edit` then `Paste`:

[image]

Now the app looks like this on my Desktop:

[image]