# How to create a droplet (drag and drop) (go) program in MacOS?

Tags: macos, go, applescript

I have a go program to create previews of pdf files. It is used in command line like this

```
myprogram my_file1.pdf my_file2.pdf ... <enter>
> my_file1.pdf
> enter resolution
> 600 <enter>
> OK
> my_file2.pdf
> enter resolution
...
```

I would like to use it just dragging the files over the program (as is on Windows), but somehow this seems hard to do in MacOS.

#### What I got so far:

It seems to Mac recognize a program as a droplet we need to create an application using **Script Editor** with a `openDocuments` method, so I did something like

```
var app = Application.currentApplication();
app.includeStandardAdditions = true;

function openDocuments(droppedItems) {
    // ...
    app.doShellScript(cmd)
}
```

And it worked! Except that I cannot get the prompt to input the resolution, so every file used the default one =/

Does any one have some idea how can I make to my program run in foreground, so the user can input the data?

Thanks you in advance

Comment: This should give you some ideas... https://stackoverflow.com/a/61726932/2836621

Comment: I am not a mac user but it looks like the real problem is that your program gets to run non-interactively. So I'd say the `cmd` in your example should run an instance of `Terminal` telling it to run your program. If Terminal follow unwritten Unix policy, it should support `-e` command-line option which tells it which (another) program to immediately execute connecting it to the terminal it emulates after startup.

Comment: Have a read here https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/ProcessDroppedFilesandFolders.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016239-CH53-SW1 I think you'll need to iterate through the dropped files and ask user for resolution of each one, then run your `go` script feeding it the answers. Try and get started iterating through the dropped files and folks might feel more inclined to help if you show some code.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments.  
The terminal non-interactively makes sense, but it seems no way to tell to `doShellScript` do different.  
I will try a bit more, but I think the only way is do some logic in the droplet script as Mark suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it worked!
The trick was instead do `app.doShellScript(cmd)` I should run the command with `Application("Terminal").doScript(cmd)`