# Making an executable app from a shell script on macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, shell, spyder

I want to make an app bundle from a shell script which executes an application, the Spyder IDE, to execute it via spotlight.

The code is:

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup spyder &
```

I created an app bundle named `Spyder.app` with the folder `Contents` and the subfolder `MacOS`, which includes the shell script `Spyder`. I made the script executable with the command `chmod ugo+x`.

Unfortunately, the App bundle doesn't open Spyder when I double click on it in the Finder. But it opens when I type in `open -a Spyder.app` in the Terminal. I guess it has something to do with the path. Has someone an idea how to fix this?

Actually when I double click at the shell script, additionally to Spyder the Terminal opens. So I have to close it manually. Is it possible to prevent the Terminal to pop up?

Comment: Did you create the Info.plist which specifies the appropriate script-exec in Contents/MacOS to launchservices?

Comment: Hey, no i didn't. Could you give an example how it has to look making things work?

Comment: I think you want something like this... https://stackoverflow.com/a/61726932/2836621

Comment: Thank you, that doesn't help. I even tried the following templet https://github.com/thedzy/run-your-script-as-an-application which should provide exactly what I want but it doesn't work. Maybe it has something to do with Catalina.

Comment: Why don't you put `open -a Spyder.app` in your script?

Comment: @manaleak90 Here is a simple example https://gist.github.com/Benitoite/926ffacf218b88baca0b89940639c4ac

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, adding info.plist doesn't change anything. I changed the script to ping -c 10 praxistipps.chip.de. The App opens for the time to ping 10 times the website, then closes without opening the terminal. When I double click at the script it does. So it seems that the problem is related with the terminal which can't be called by the Application.

Comment: Note: Info.plist starts with capital-I.